# Storage assignment algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm trying to code a storage assignment algorithm but I'm not sure what the best way would be to model the warehouse the algorithm runs on.

The warehouse consists of shelves that can fit one item per storage location, walking ways and measuring points. Items can only be retrieved from the front of the storage locations denoted with broken lines. (The image below is just a basic representation of the warehouse. In the final version it is supposed to be tested with various amounts of storage locations and SKUs.

[image]

The idea is to measure the distance from a measuring point to a storage location for each SKU and minimize the overall distances.

*The algorithm itself follows a two step approach:
First a simple greedy is used to find a feasible starting solution.
Secondly, the main algorithm is an adapeted version of binary search that runs multiple
binary search iterations through the set of potentially optimal maximum distance combinations obtained from the greedy before and assigns the SKUs to the storage location that minimizes the objective value.*

My basic idea was to model the storage locations as a graph from each measuring point to the storage locations with arcs representing the distance but I'm not 100% sure if this would make sense.

So what are your ideas?

Disclaimer: The main idea is based on the paper 'Scattered Storage: How to Distribute Stock Keeping Units All Around a Mixed-Shelves Warehouse' published by Boysen & Weidinger in 2018.

Comment: Couldn't post images in the question. This is the basic layout of the warehouse [link] (https://imgur.com/a/9m3tSgB) [M1= measuring points, blank= walking ways lines= storage locations]

Comment: This seems like a language-agnostic algorithm question at this point, so I removed the Python tags, which seem irrelevant and will overly restrict the scope of the answers. Feel free to roll back if you disagree. I'm also not sure I fully grasp the problem, so a bit more clarity seems in order to make this answerable (I could just be missing it though).

Comment: I just added the Py tag because that's the only language I'm more or less capable of X,D. My problem is that I need to figure out how to represent the warehouse in a meaningful way for the algorithm to run on

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. However, I think you might be looking at the problem from the wrong angle. Rather than searching for where to put it, find the "cost function" from all measuring points to all storage locations. Then have each storage location store it's cost. Then you throw all the (available) storage locations into a priority queue.

If you need a storage location pull the next one from the priority queue. If a location frees up, add it the queue.

Make a grid graph that represents the path that can be traversed. IE: if (0,0) is the top left corner. Then there is no direct connection between (0,1) and (1,1) as that storage isn't accessible from the left side. However, there is connection between (1,0) and (1,1). Once you have this, you can run all shortest paths to find all the distances. You'll likely need to be able to mark squares as either a) Measuring location, b) walkway or c) Storage location.

The cost function and related bits is the real tricky thing to get right in terms of "real world practicality". Here are some things to consider:

1. In simple terms you are just looking for the distances to all measuring stations from each storage location and the cost is probably the average. In more complex terms, you may need to consider throughput. By this I mean it may not make sense to take something out a storage location, put something back, take it out again, put it back again and so on. That may cause bottlenecks as now everyone is trying to store stuff in the same general area and you might have some traffic issues with too many people in the same area. In this case, you may need to add some "randomness" to the measurements. For example the middle 2 have the same weight, but are on opposite ends of the warehouse (in theory). It would be best if some randomness was used to ensure there is a 50:50 chance of either one being the next place an item goes. Though that alone isn't likely to be enough if this is a real issue.
2. You may not actually want to minimize distance to a all measuring locations practically speaking. There are likely cases where certain SKU's are more relevant distance wise to certain measuring locations. In which case, you may want to bias the priority value in that direction. IE: An SKU that is almost always going to be moved to M1 should more likely be placed in a storage location closer to that. Of course that requires something more complex than a priority queue to get working right as you need to be able to search the available storage locations for the one closest to M1.
3. You may need to consider order items can be stored. IE: If a storage location is 2 deep (all the ones you have are 1 deep), you may want to fill the location further back first. Though I suspect this probably isn't the issue.
4. Vertical storage locations. Once you have a 2D grid working, a 3D grid isn't significantly more complex to implement, useful if storage locations are actually multiple level allowing for items to be placed on different shelves or something (or just stacked). The issue here is just like #3. Do you fill things storage locations up top to bottom? Bottom to top? Or random order? Of course, quite possible your needs are such that vertical storage isn't possible or simply impractical (too tall, too fragile, unstackable, no shelving, etc).
5. #2 This can be further enhanced by keeping note of which items are being fetched/placed. The system can also track how long it typically takes to fetch/place items and direct placement of SKUs to other areas if others are expected to be in that area around the time the item is being fetched/placed in it's storage location.